# Node.Js using tmi.js and cleverbot.io trouble

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, twitch

I am currently having trouble with a twitch bot that I am trying to make. I decided to try out Node.js, but I am having a couple of errors. I am using the tmi.js and cleverbot.io libraries, installed via npm. My code so far is as shown below:

```
var tmi = require('tmi.js');
var cleverbot = require('cleverbot.io');


var options = {
  options: {
    debug:  true
  },

  connections: {
    cluster: "aws",
    reconnect: true
  },

  identity: {
    username: "TwitchCleverBot",
    password: "APIKEY"
  },

  channels: ["klausmana"]
};

var client = new tmi.client(options);
var  smartbot = new 
cleverbot('APIUSERNAME','APIKEY');

client.connect();

client.on("chat", function(channel, userstate, message, self){

  if(self){
    return;
  }

  if(message.toLowerCase().includes("cleverbot")){
    var lowmessage = message.toLowerCase();
    var newmessage = lowmessage.replace("cleverbot", " ");
    smartbot.create(function(err, session){

      smartbot.ask(newmessage, function(err, response){
        client.action(channel, response);
      });

    });
  }

});
```

This is all the code I have in my app.js so far. The error occurs when I try to make a request to the cleverbot.io, so the tmi.js part works (with as much as I know). It gives me the following error:

[image: Nodejs Error]

Apparently, I am trying to make a JSON parse to a html file, but I really do not understand where and how that happens if anyone is able to help, I would really appreciate it.

P.S : The project is indeed a twitch bot, but my problem was in Node.js and Javascript, so that is why I decided to turn to StackOverflow

Comment: i am thinking that you are not Authorized correctly since you are getting `<!DOCTYPE html>` as a response, which might be `401` page rendered as a response. Full HTML response might give you exact information

Comment: @KukicVladimir I am authorized correctly, but I think that the problem is on their side. I tried their sandbox, and even that didn't work, so the problem could just be on their servers or something?

Comment: maybe contact them orwait a bit to see if it gets resolved. your code looks ok.

Comment: ok, thanks for the help